# ATSAMD11C SERCOM I2C Pin Assignment

Tags: i2c, arm

I am planning on using the ATSAMD11C14 (SOIC14 package) for a project that requires USB, 2 I2C busses, and some GPIO.

The device has two SERCOMs, each has 4 pins assigned to it. When used in 2 wire I2C mode, only two pins are required for communications. Does this mean that the other two pins assigned to the SERCOM can be used as GPIO?

I took a look through the data sheet, but cannot find the information I am looking for. Apologies if it was there and I just missed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each GPIO pin must be separately configured anyway, and every SERCOM section warns that used pins must be configured for the alternative function of SERCOM, it means you can configure or leave other pins as GPIO.

Comment: Thanks, was confused about the wording.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure, you can check your configuration with [Atmel START](https://start.atmel.com/). This is a graphical interface to set-up Atmel microcontrollers. This also includes GPIO and SERCOM settings. It even has the functionality to setup your clocks, drivers and more.

Comment: Can you expand this answer to make it less reliant on the link?